# floating vertical alignment in excel 2013 merged cell

Tags: excel, merge, cell, vertical-alignment, excel-2013

I have a merged cell that spans about 700-800 rows. Is there a way to make the value of the cell float in the visible range of the sheet?

I really hate the limitation of the vertical alignment being limited to top, center and bottom. Surely there is a way to make the content "float" in the visible part of the sheet I am scrolled to?

i.e. I am scrolled to rows 530-560, and neither vertical alignment options allows me to see the value, but if the cell content value would float in the center of the visible range, it would be somewhere around row 545.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot...
A trick can be to put a "Float" Textbox (Shape) on the screen in correspondance of the column you want to show (Same Width, 1 or 2 cells height) and add a little sub to move in base of SelectionChange event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set kk = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 2"))

    kk.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Range("A1").Value
    kk.Top = Windows(1).VisibleRange.Top + Windows(1).Height / 2 - Range("A1").Height * 2
End Sub
```

It's not connected to Scroll event, because don't exist. There was some sample how to implement, but sometimes crash... I don't like.